# Overload operator>> to delete a node from a binary tree

Tags: c++, operator-overloading, binary-search-tree, nodes

I have the following classes:

```
class Node 
{
private:
    char* m_key;
    Node* left;
    Node* right;

public:
    Node() : m_key(nullptr), left(nullptr), right(nullptr) {}

    Node(const char* key) 
    {
        this->m_key = new char[strlen(key) + 1];
        strcpy_s(this->m_key, strlen(key) + 1, key);

        left = nullptr;
        right = nullptr;
    }

    friend class BinSTree;
};
```

```
class BinSTree 
{
private:
    Node* root;
public:
    BinSTree() : root(nullptr) {}

    friend std::fstream& operator>>(std::fstream& in, Node* p);
    Node* deleteNode(Node* p, const char* key);

    ~BinSTree();
};
```

I want to overload the `operator>>` so when I execute the following code :

```
Node test("Key");
BinSTree bst;

bst>>test;
```

the node `test` is deleted from the bst. The problem is that I can't access the private members from `Node` and also can't access members of class `BinSTree`. `BinSTree` is a class that contains the root of a binary tree.`Node` is a class that represents a node.

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: My question is how can I overload the operator>> so I can access to the private members of the classes so I can delete the ```Node test``` from the ```BinSTree bst```?

Comment: You are using and so I assume that you already know the keyword `friend`? Where is the problem?

Comment: Please add the error message you are facing and any relevant code (e.g. the definition of your `operator>>`).

Comment: In the function ```std::fstream& operator>>(std::fstream& in, Node* p) { }``` I can't access ```m_key``` for ```p``` also can't access the function ```Node* deleteNode(Node* p, const char* key);``` or ```Node* root;```

Comment: You need to declare the function `operator>>` as friend in `Node`

Comment: @ThomasSablik That does not explain why there is no access to `deleteNode`. The problem is most likely something else (like namespaces or something).

Comment: @MaxLanghof Because `deleteNode` is a member function of `BinSTree` and not of `Node`. There is no object of type `BinSTree` in the function `operator>>(std::fstream& in, Node* p)`. `Node` has no reference to `BinSTree`. How can `deleteNode` be accessed from `operator>>`?

Comment: Declared ```operator>>``` as friend in ```Node``` and it solved the first problem, as a side question, shouldn't the ```friend class BinSTree;``` grand access also for the ```m_key``` ? And how can I access any function/member from ```BinSTree``` ?

Comment: Why does your `operator>>` declaration involve `std::fstream`? You want that operator to operate on `BinSTree`s, not `std::fstream`s...

Comment: There is a memory leak in `Node`. You allocate memory in one constructor but you don't delete it. For each call to `new` you need one call to `delete`.

Comment: Yes, `Node` is allowed to access private elements but it has no reference to any `BinSTree` object. How could an object of type `Node` access such elements? How do you call `deleteNode`??

Comment: I don't understand what I code should I provide if I don't have anything wrote in the function because I can't access the functions\members from the class ```BinSTree```. Also I don't expect an object ```Node``` to have access to anything in class ```BinSTree```.

Comment: How do you want to call `deleteNode`? There is no object of type `BinSTree` in `operator>>` and `Node` has no reference to `BinSTree`. `deleteNode` is a member function of `BinSTree`. You need an object to call this function. Also `bst>>test;` won't call `operator>>(std::fstream& in, Node* p)` because `bst` is not of type `std::fstream`.

Comment: `BinSTree` is a type. Your `operator>>` should operate on _instances_ of `BinSTree`. There is no instance of `BinSTree` in the function `std::fstream& operator>>(std::fstream& in, Node* p)`, only an instance of `std::fstream`. You don't want to do anything with `std::fstream`. Why is it in that function signature? A correct function signature would be `void operator>>(BinSTree& tree, Node* p)`.

Comment: A good way to make sure you have a [mcve] is to put your code into https://godbolt.org/z/A17aif and check that you get the same error message there. "I don't have the code because it doesn't work" is nothing we can work with.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't have access to members of `BinSTree` because first of all your `operator>>` does not operate on `BinSTree` at all - it operates on `std::fstream&` and `Node*`.

What your code provides is a function for "extracting" `Node*`s from a `std::fstream` - it has no relation whatsoever with `BinSTree`.

The correct signature for the operator you want is

```
void operator>>(BinSTree& tree, Node* p)
```

or

```
BinSTree& void operator>>(BinSTree& tree, Node* p)
```

(the latter would allow you to chain node extractions).

Comment: I understand now, that I can't access the members from ```BinSTree``` from this function, that the definition of it is incorrect for what I want to do. I tried replacing the function with what you suggested but on both cases I get errors. First one ```"too many parameters for this operator function"```, second one ```"expected an identifier"```. This error I get when i declare them in the class.

Comment: @OvidiuFirescu That operator should be a free function. Don't put it in the class. https://godbolt.org/z/8bVdsp

Comment: @OvidiuFirescu Please add a [mcve] of what you tried.

Comment: Ok, so I declared the function ```void operator>>(BinSTree& tree, Node& p);``` outside of the class, and it worked exactly as I expected it to work, I implemented the code for it and tested with ```bst>>test;``` and all good. Thanks a lot really helpful @MaxLanghof. Thomas it's hard to give an example when all I did was just copy paste the declaration of the function he suggested in my class exactly the same nothing more (without implementation or anything else). Also is possible for this function to be declared and implemented in a class?

Comment: @OvidiuFirescu You got compiler errors. That means that you had code that you compiled. It would be really helpful for us to have this code with these error messages to analyse and debug it. You were lucky that this time some people guessed your problem without knowing your code.

Comment: @OvidiuFirescu Again: If you want to ask about an error, provide code that has _that exact error_. Not the last code you had without an error, or the last code with some different error. There are so many things you could be doing wrong that we have to keep guessing what it is that you did wrong, even if you "just copy paste" things (point in case: you "just copy paste"d an incorrect declaration for `operator>>` from somewhere into your class which led to this question).

Comment: I never declared and implemented an ```operator>>``` in other way (in all cases when I implemented it I used it to read data) and this was something new that I didn't know exactly how to do it, so I started with what I knew. Now I understood why I didn't have access to the members of ```BinSTree``` or members of ```Node```. I tried as best as I could to explain the situation and the problem in the initial question, I specified what function/classes I had, what problems I had, what I expected the code to do. I will try better in the next questions thanks for the advice and help.

Comment: @OvidiuFirescu To explain our perspective: You said you couldn't access the _private_ members from your implementation of `operator>>`. Since you provided a `friend` declaration (with an incorrect signature) I _guessed_ that you got the signature right in the _definition_ (where you wrote the function body). But since you never showed your implementation of `operator>>` where you tried to access those members we couldn't tell whether you did the _implementation_ right and just messed up the signature in the `friend` declaration or whether there was another mistake. In the end it was the latter

Comment: You're right and I understand that I should have said something in the initial question about the implementation and what code or anything else I have in it. The only reason I didn't provide the code for the implementation and I said this in one of the comments later on, is that I didn't have any the function was empty. Should have said from the start that is empty and show how I try to access other members/functions in it. Sorry